# Two different front pages with different themes

Tags: 7

So I have the following problem. I created an entry page with module [front](http://drupal.org/project/front) that has two links. To categoryA and categoryB. Now I want these two categories to have different front pages with different themes.

Any ideas on how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module?

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional
>   properties exposed by other modules.

Comment: This module is very useful but I need two frontpages. So let's say my entry page is www.example.com and my two links are to www.example.com/categoryA and www.example.com/categoryB. I want these two pages to be front pages.

Comment: Sorry, but when you say front pages..are you talking essentially having two separate sites?  Check [this](http://www.palantir.net/blog/multi-headed-drupal) blog post out from the awesome guys at Palantir if this is the case.  Sounds like Organic Groups might really be your thing if I'm right.

Comment: Very interesting post. I am trying to figure out a solution now with organic groups. But I have difficulties using different themes for different groups. Any ideas?

Comment: [OG_Theme](http://drupal.org/project/og_theme) should help with that.  I remember it being a bit unusual to use, but there's an awesome Lullabot article [here](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/organic-groups-drupal-7) with some useful suggestions.

Comment: That's a great tutorial. I had to read it 10 times but I managed to get everything ready. Still not sure how to make two front pages with OG though.

Comment: Surely you'd just create two organic groups, have one at www.homepage.com/group1 and one at www.homepage.com/group2.  Theme them, and let Organic groups split the content around for you.  Two front pages.  Unless you're looking for two separate domains...that's a completely different kettle of fish.

Comment: so in order to have two different front pages www.example.com/categoryA and www.example.com/categoryB I really need two separate domains (or subdomains). Right?

Comment: No.  I'm really not sure I follow you now.  Your Organic Groups can be your front pages by just pointing your browser/links/whatever to them.  You might want to expand on your question slightly to better explain your use case.

Comment: You are right. Maybe I am not clear. Let me go back some steps and revise my problem.